# Realtek HD Audio, Using Both Internal Mic And Headset Mic

Tags: audio, microphone, recording, headset, realtek-hd-audio

So my issue is that my Sager laptop came preinstalled with Realtek High Definition Audio manager. This manager is the problem, as it won't allow me differentiate between the headset microphone and the internal microphone. So while playing games like No Man's Sky, even if I mute my headset's microphone(with a switch beside the volume), my laptop's internal microphone still picks up my voice... In device manager, there's no separation of my headset and internal mics, but rather Microphone(Realtek High Definition Audio) as the only audio input device, and in the software for Realtek HD Audio, there are no options to correct this. 
Can anyone help me disable my laptops internal mic, while allowing my headset mic to work?

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Home, x64-based PC
System Model: P65_67HSHP

Answer (score 0):

> This manager is the problem, as it won't allow me differentiate between the headset microphone and the internal microphone.

No, it isn't. There's no problem at all. It's just how your hardware has been designed. Some (mostly desktop's) sound cards/chips allow for distinct input devices but many new laptops' sound devices using a single jack like phones/tablets don't.